# Flash - LocalConnection between Projector file and SWF file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, projector, localconnection

A long time ago I created two files called alpha.exe and bravo.swf. alpha and bravo communicate to each other using a localconnection. These files were created using Flash MX with AS1 and Flash Player 6 - they worked perfectly!

Now I am building new versions of alpha and bravo using Flash CS6 with AS3 and Flash Player 14. If I publish alpha and bravo both as .exe (windows projector) files the local connection works ok. If I publish alpha and bravo both as .swf files the local connection works ok too. If however I make alpha a .exe file and bravo a .swf file the local connection does not work.

Does anyone know why?

I am scouring the internet at the moment but haven't found anything to point me in the right direction as of yet. I'm also trying different publishing options in CS6 (Flash Player and Actionscript versions), but no luck there either... yet...

Answer (score 1):

In your EXE you probably need to choose between local access and network access.  As a security precaution, local SWF playback can do one or the other, but not both.  The default (in publish settings) is for local access.  If your SWF is being served by a webserver, even if it is localhost, they are now in separate security domains and can't communicate.

If you change to network access, they will be able to communicate, but the EXE will likely not be able to load SWFs or text from the local file system.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I'll start experimenting with the publishing settings. It's only running on my desktop at the moment, I don't need this particular project to run on a webserver.